# Python machine learning script for text classification

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, data-science, text-classification

I need help on writing a python script foe the following task.

Training data format:

```
Record contains:            Result:
-------------------              ---------
(x,f,r,t,w)                   ->     Positive
(x,f,d,z,w,m,d)               ->    Positive
(x,f,e,o,p)                   ->     Negative
(x,f,r,t,w,d)                 ->    Positive
(z,q,4)                       ->    Negative
```

And after that if i give a record like

```
(c,r,s,w,f,h,t,d)
```

then it should return a score based on how negative or positive it's.  Note that the result is not positive or negative rather it should be a number between let's say for example 1 - 1000, 0 means most negative and 1000 means most positive.

Comment: Factorise your inputs, and then feed vectors into a recurrent neural network...

Answer (score 0):

Since your input is a sequence with various lengths. It is recommended to use LSTM RNN. You can use a sequence of LSTMs to receive the input sequence, and then aggregate the output of the LSTMs and do regression on that.

More about that in (http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lstm.html)